# How to affect descendants of a modified parent class in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, inheritance, delphi-7

Let's say I have two classes in `Unit1`: `TParent = class(TCustomControl)` and `TDescendant = class(TParent)` and they both have a lot of methods, fields and properties.

In `Unit2` I need to modify `TParent`. Let's say I only need to modify a single method, `Method1`, in a very simple way that doesn't really affect anything outside itself (say, print a text in red color instead of black). I also need `TDescendant` to be affected by this modification (so every time it calls `Method1` the modified `Method1` is executed).

Is there a way to do that in **Delphi 7**, **without modifying `Unit1` and without copying the entire `TDescendant` class into `Unit2`**?

On top of that I really need the class names to remain the same (I'm simply trying to modify a method in a 3rd party control without creating a whole new control to do it).

I made an interceptor class of `TParent` in `Unit2`, but I don't know how (if at all possible) to "tell" `TDescendant` to become a descendant of the interceptor class instead of the original.

Comment: So, I did not understand the question. Why don't you just change the source? Is the method virtual or static? Could you use a runtime hook?

Comment: I always prefer not to copy entire units just for the sake of changing a few lines. It's much cleaner if you can just properly override ONLY what you actually want to change. That's a personal preference I guess. The method that I currently want to change is a private virtual method, but my question doesn't specify this because I'm also interested in a more general answer (what if tomorrow I want to do the same with a static method?). Using a runtime hook is not a technique I'm really familiar with, maybe that's what I'm looking for? Can you give me an example?

Comment: While it can be fun to mess around with virtual methods, inheritance chains or hook/detour methods I actually would modify the 3rd party control unit.

Comment: I don't understand why you don't change the source. Why not do that? It works.

Comment: @David I already explained why in my previous comment. It's not that I can't do it, that's actually the solution I'm currently using, I just don't like it and I'm looking for a better one if one exists, that's all. Whenever I have to change something in an existing control, I'm always using interceptor classes, which work great and for me it's much cleaner than unnecessarily copying entire units into my app's source. I don't believe anyone would prefer the latter if they could use an interceptor class. So this is the same thing, it's just a more complicated situation.

Comment: I use revision control for this. Then when you get new releases of the third party code, you can merge it with your mods. That's the right solution. Safe and simple.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know this is not possible without some serious low level hacks (pointer/memory based). Therefor I would not suggest is at all... (also I don't know the actual answer to that solution).

When you only want to add some extra methods to the `TParent` class, you can use helper classes (Delphi XE+ - maybe even earlier versions).

Ex.

```
TParentHelper = class helper for TParent
public
  procedure MyMethod(param: string);
end;
```

Now you can dos stuff like:

```
uses
  MyParentHelperU;

Procedure test(D: TDescendant);
begin
  D.MyMethod('test');
end;
```

Notes:

1. you need to include the unit in which the helper class in defined, in order to use this functionality.
2. You can only add methods to the class (and descendants), for which the helper class has been assigned. You cannot add properties or fields.
3. Protected properties can be accessed by the helperclass, but are not always shown by the IDE

Comment: He wants to modify the behaviour of a private function. That's entirely different from extending the class with new ones.